# How can I make a custom progress bar for a YouTube embed animate smoothly?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Theres something about a progressing YouTube video that makes it difficult to produce a smoothly animating progress bar. Even YouTube's built in progress bar isnt smooth. Yet I think there must be a way to do it.

I'm using custom controls for a YouTube embed and my progress bar is moving along in a jumpy manner rather than smoothly. Here's the code:

```
vidClock = setInterval(function() {
    if (state == 1) {
        var time = player.getCurrentTime();
        var percent = (time / duration) * 100;
        $seekSlider.css({
            'width' : percent + '%'
        });
    }
}, 100);
```

This variable origins aren't all shown but what they represent should be apparent. How can I make the bar move smoothly?

I tried adding a CSS transition effect to the element and also tried setting smaller intervals such as 10,20, and 30 (and after suggestion, have tried using JQuery animate).

Example, using `$.animate` as suggested by an answer below is not smooth: http://jsfiddle.net/e11oy0eu/290/

Comment: There must be some way to get a smooth progress bar animation. I notice even youtube's progress bar isnt smooth, but it seems like there must be a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .animate() function:

```
vidClock = setInterval(function() {
    if (state == 1) {
        var time = player.getCurrentTime();
        var percent = (time / duration) * 100;
        $seekSlider.animate({
            'width' : percent + '%'
        },500);
    }
}, 500);
```

Or use CSS animations:

CSS:

```
.progress {
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
vidClock = setInterval(function() {
    if (state == 1) {
        var time = player.getCurrentTime();
        var percent = (time / duration) * 100;
        $seekSlider.css({
            'width' : percent + '%'
        });
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately the result is only slightly better, still very jumpy when I try this in intervals of 5, 10, 30, 100, or 150.

Comment: Do you have an example to see what is happening?

Comment: Ill make a JSFiddle

Comment: getCurrentTime() seems to only update every ~500ms or so, try using that interval.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e11oy0eu/283/ updating the position just twice per second results in a choppy animation it would seem.

Comment: You have to keep the animation duration the same as the update interval in order to keep it smooth.

Comment: I didnt see much of an improvement in smoothness when I made that alteration to the JS Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/e11oy0eu/290/ - Still a very rough animation.

Comment: If its from pausing & unpausing, clear the vidClock interval every time handleState is called.

Comment: Or you could test the other solution I added above, but other than that I think that's the smoothest as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

I chose a different approach for fixing your problem, first of all I added [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) to the project because as [Alon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026271/alon) said in his answer, it gives you a little better animations, then **instead of setting a timer and changing the progress bar size based on the current time of the player**, I created a progress bar that **always animates to 100%**, then used some events to stop the progress bar when the video play stops(by user or when it stops for buffering). While this strategy has its downsides, it gives you smoother animation.

Also for an even smoother animation, instead of changing the div width, I changed the `.progress` div's position to `absolute` and moved it using the `transform:translateX` property.(I am not sure that how much effective was this change, maybe it was not effective at all).

```
.progress-container {
  width: 640px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

After these changes, the handleState function looks like this:

```
function handleState(state) {
  var $seekSlider = $('.progress');
  var $seekContainer = $('.progress-container');

  if (state == 1) { // when player starts playing
    duration = player.getDuration();
    currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
    currentLocation = ((currentTime/duration) * 100).toFixed(4);

    $seekSlider
      .velocity('stop')
      .velocity({
        'translateX': currentLocation + '%'
      }, {duration: 0})
      .velocity({
        'translateX': '100%'
      }, {
        duration: Math.floor((duration-currentTime) * 1000),
        easing: 'linear'
      });
  }

  if (state == 2 || state == 3 || state == 0) {
    $seekSlider.velocity('stop');

    if (state == 3) {
      duration = player.getDuration();
      currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
      currentLocation = ((currentTime/duration) * 100).toFixed(4);

      $seekSlider.velocity({
        'translateX': currentLocation + '%'
      }, {duration: 0});
    }

    if (state == 0) {
        $seekSlider.velocity({
        'translateX': '100%'
      }, {duration: 0});
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the working result and complete code with some comments in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e11oy0eu/293/), Also I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/alireza-ahmadi/e503776fff7abd1e66dcffb630b63b7d/revisions?diff=split) that shows the differences between your script and my script.

Comment: And sorry for my weak grammar ;)

Answer (score 2):

The chunky progressing is not only caused by the `getCurrentTime` function, but also by the way you are resizing the progress bar. Even though you are setting the CSS `width` in percent, it will always render as whole pixels. You can use `transform` instead, which will render "half" pixels as well.

Next, to overcome the limitation of `getCurrentTime` not updating on each call, you can save its value in a variable and increase it manually with the timer interval:

```
function handleState(state) {
  var $seekSlider = $('.progress');
  var $seekContainer = $('.progress-container');
  if (state == 1) {
    duration = player.getDuration();
    var prevTime = 0;
    var elapsed = 0;
    vidClock = setInterval(function() {
      elapsed += 0.05; // Increase with timer interval
      if ((state == 1) && (seeking == false)) {
        var time = player.getCurrentTime();
        if (time != prevTime) {
          elapsed = time; // Update if getCurrentTime was changed
          prevTime = time;
        }
        var percent = (elapsed / duration);
        $seekSlider.css({
          'transform': 'scaleX(' + percent + ')'
        });
      }
    }, 50);
  } else {
    clearInterval(vidClock);
  }
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XL2000/e11oy0eu/295/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Velocity.js. Its animation is a lot smoother than jQuery and the configuration is as simple as the jQuery one.

look at this comparison: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/silky-smooth-web-animation-with-velocityjs--cms-24266